# Laravel don't load bootstrap on mobile device

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with the display of my site on mobile, I explain to you:

I state that I checked all the tags and the structure of my code there is nothing abnormal.

when I look at the site from the browser of my pc in mobile version everything seems to work, including the javascript bootstrap part

when I use my bootstrap phone it doesn't work and I see everything very small and not responsive

I have already tried to manually load the bootstrap CDN in the basic layout including the cdn of its javascript but nothing to do.

in desk version therefore on normal monitors everything works perfectly.

what can I do? thank you so much

Comment: do you have the viewport meta within your html code?

Comment: Welcome to SO @amepro ! When you're posting a question, you should always include snippets of your code - people will generally be more able and willing to help you when they can see WHAT you've done and WHAT you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hello, @Thamerbelfkih thank you so much, i have add this property in my viewport user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0   and now work. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to achieve that you should add this meta inside the `<head></head>` tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

for more information [viewport meta tag](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/audits/has-viewport-meta-tag)